# Spring boot - Delete big amount of data rows from table

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

What is the best way to delete big amount of records in Spring boot with Oracle Database ?
How to implement best way to delete in batches ? Should we fetch the id's to delete first or
it can be done in same operation ? Should everything be in one transaction or it's better to split them ?

I tried to fetch first the id's and then to separate them by List.partition(ids, batchsize) and execute delete for each in transaction.

Comment: If you can query the ids you can also write a single shot delete.

Comment: Isn't it better to be on batches ?

Comment: Depends on the size, nonetheless you can still do that in a one shot delete instead of retrieving the ids and then do a batch delete. There is no one right answer it all depends on your situation (number of rows, database, transaction islolation level, how busy is the database, type of data, amount of data, tables involved etc. etc., so there is no golden hammer, silver bullet solution. It all depends).

Answer (score 0):

How to implement best way to delete in batches ? --- best way always depends on your requirements.

Should we fetch the id's to delete first or it can be done in same operation ?- if you have ids handy then you can directly delete if not then obviously you will need fetch and delete , you can use native sql query to execute delete without operation without ids.

Should everything be in one transaction or it's better to split them ?

- here comes what you want to delete and what is the significance of delete operation if its fails in between ,
- if one batch fails and another is success whether your app will be in
  inconsistent state ?

Remember delete and inserts will cost your w.r.t your indexing of db and probably application performance overhead. Try to avoid it using code and instead of delete ,update it as invalid with some another column and have some trigger/TTL/Cron Job to periodically cleanup that table when your database/application is not/less active.

Comment: Can you enumerate what "big" means? How many rows are you trying to delete and how may rows in the table?

Comment: I think you commented in answer instead of question :)

Comment: For example 1 millions rows where table contains 200 million rows?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, performing deletions in batches is a common approach to manage large-scale data deletions efficiently.

1. **Using Spring Data JPA**

If you're using Spring Data JPA, one efficient way is to leverage the deleteInBatch method provided by Spring Data JPA repositories to delete entities in batch.

Here is an example:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class YourService {

    @Transactional
    public void deleteInBatches() {
        int pageSize = 500; // Adjust the page size as needed
        int pageNumber = 0;
        Page<Entity> page;

        do {
            page = entityRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize));
            List<Entity> entities = page.getContent();
            entityRepository.deleteInBatch(entities);
            pageNumber++;
        } while (!page.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

You should change the query according to your requirement.

**Things to Consider:**

1. **Optimize Batch Size:** Experiment with different batch sizes to find the optimal one. Larger batch sizes might be more efficient but could also lock resources for longer periods.
2. **Transactions:** Splitting deletes into smaller transactions might reduce the time resources are locked and improve performance. Evaluate the trade-offs and potential impact on your system.

Comment: Yeah i also tried something similar. But as you said isn't it better transaction to be into smaller transactions. In this case when the whole method is anotated with @Transactional, wouldn't be all data rollbacked if something happens ?

Comment: And also what do you think what is optimal time for example for deleting 100k records if the entity has no relations ?

Comment: You can consider using nested transactions to break the large transaction into smaller, independent ones. This allows for a form of partial rollback, meaning that if an error occurs within one transaction, only that specific transaction will be rolled back, not affecting the changes made in previous batches.
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW),
meaning it will run in a new transaction.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does and even worse will be terribly slow with large results. It will fill up the first level cache for which dirty checks will be done. It is still one transaction and not multiple.